# rspamd: Bayesian filter doesn't appear to be working

Tags: rspamd

I am setting up rspamd.

It seems to work quite effectively, however one thing I've noticed is this log entry in my rspamd.log every time I receive a message:

> 2019-05-03 11:36:24 #13015(normal) <0a2236>; task; bayes_classify: skip classification as ham class has not enough learns: 0, 200 required

However, the number of learns (currently zero) does not appear to be going up. Is there something I should have done or configured to make it start learning?

Answer (score 0):

You should learn Bayesian classifier using `rspamc learn_ham` and `rspamc learn_spam` [commands](https://rspamd.com/doc/faq.html#how-can-i-learn-messages) (by hand or using some wrapper script or [IMAPSieve](https://wiki.dovecot.org/HowTo/AntispamWithSieve)) or WebUI `Scan/Learn` tab.

Also Rspamd supports autolearning, but it is generally not recommended as it is harmful in case of false positives. If you decide to enable autolearning, I would recommend to fine tune Rspamd configuration first, make sure the statistical module is already trained well enough and set wisely high thresholds to avoid false positives as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I made the mistake of deleting all my spam mails from the linked junk folder instead of leaving them there for rspamd to learn from.

Watch out for loglines like:

```
skip obtaining bayes tokens for BAYES_SPAM of classifier bayes: not enough learns 0; 200 required
```